# Name error when creating a new function in python

Tags: python-3.x, user-defined-functions, nameerror

```
import math
def paint_calc(height, width, coverage):
    area= height * width
    num_of_cans= math.ceil(area/coverage)


width = int(input("What is the width?"))
height = int(input("What is the height?"))
coverage = 5
paint_calc(width, height, coverage)
print(f'You need {num_of_cans} of paint')
```

I made a new function in python but the second variable is giving me a name error and num_of_can is not defined when I try to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a variable inside of a function it is scoped to that the function body.  So if you attempt to use it outside it's scope, it will cause an error.

Since `num_of_cans` is defined within a function, once that function is finished executing the variable goes away.

What you could do is return `num_of_cans` from the function and redefine it in the outer scope.

Like this:

```
import math
def paint_calc(height, width, coverage):
    area= height * width
    num_of_cans= math.ceil(area/coverage)
    return num_of_cans   # return the calculated value


width = int(input("What is the width?"))
height = int(input("What is the height?"))
coverage = 5
num_of_cans = paint_calc(width, height, coverage)   # redefine variable 
print(f'You need {num_of_cans} of paint')
```